# error occurred when compare apk file md5 value existing md5

Tags: android, python

### Import hashlib library (md5 method is part of it)

```
import hashlib
```

### File to check

```
file_name = "test.apk"
```

### Correct original md5 goes here

```
original_md5 = '5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592'
```

### Open,close, read file and calculate MD5 on its contents

```
with open(file_name) as file_to_check:
    # read contents of the file
    data = file_to_check.read()
    md5_returned = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
```

### Finally compare original MD5 with freshly calculated

```
if original_md5 == md5_returned:
    print ("MD5 verified.")
else:
    print ("MD5 verification failed!.")
```

error

```
File "newhash.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = file_to_check.read()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 286: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to open the file in binary mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate a checksum (md5, sha1, etc.), you must open the file in binary mode, because you'll sum bytes values:

To be py27/py3 portable, you ought to use the `io` packages, like this:

```
import hashlib
import io


def md5sum(src):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with io.open(src, mode="rb") as fd:
        content = fd.read()
        md5.update(content)
    return md5
```

If your files are big, you may prefer to read the file by chunks to avoid storing the whole file content in memory:

```
def md5sum(src, length=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with io.open(src, mode="rb") as fd:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: fd.read(length), b''):
            md5.update(chunk)
    return md5
```

If your files are **really** big, you may also need to display progress information. You can do that by calling a callback function which prints or logs the amount of calculated bytes:

```
def md5sum(src, callback, length=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    calculated = 0
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with io.open(src, mode="rb") as fd:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: fd.read(length), b''):
            md5.update(chunk)
            calculated += len(chunk)
            callback(calculated)
    return md5
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you read the file as a text file and not binary file. Don't know whether you use python2 or python3 but for both cases you can found how to read bytes from a file and not interpret them as strings.